# overloaded + and - operators, trouble figuring out how to check if the "amount" being passed in is negative

Tags: c++, linked-list, singly-linked-list

I have overloaded these operators to help me traverse a doubly linked list, but have run into a small bug, and being still new to c++ I am stuck.  I never accounted for it the "amount" entered in would be a negative number.  So I think I need to put a check in each operator for a negative number, because it will dramatically change the way I traverse the list, example, if im pointing at node 5 and I +(-3) I would want it to move backwards three nodes, the same with the -, 5 - (-3) would be go ahead three nodes.  the logic seems easy, but the syntax is confusing.  Here are the operators overloaded:

```
template <typename T>
typename doublyLinkedList<T>::iterator doublyLinkedList<T>::iterator::operator+(const int amount) const {
    doublyLinkedList<T>::iterator tempClone(*this);
    tempClone.pastBoundary=false;
    T i;

    for(i=0; i < amount; i++)
    {   
       if(tempClone.current->forward == NULL)
       {
          tempClone.pastBoundary =true;
       }else
       {
          ++tempClone;
       }
    }

    if(tempClone.pastBoundary == true)
    {
       return *this;
    }else
    {
        return tempClone;   
    }
}
template <typename T>
typename doublyLinkedList<T>::iterator doublyLinkedList<T>::iterator::operator-(const int amount) const {
    doublyLinkedList<T>::iterator tempClone(*this);
    tempClone.pastBoundary=false;
    T i;

    for(i=0; i < amount; i++)

       {    
        if(tempClone.current->backward == NULL)
       {
          tempClone.pastBoundary =true;
       }else
       {
          --tempClone;
       }
    }


    if(tempClone.pastBoundary == true)
    {
       return *this;
    }else
    {
        return tempClone;   
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`if(amount = (-amount))` - unless amount is 0, this is always true.

And it needs to go before the for-loop. In fact, I would probably do:

```
if (amount < 0) return this->operator-(-amount);
```

and vise versa for the other operator.

Answer (score 0):

In the beginning of operator+, add:

```
if (amount <0) {
  operator-(-amount);
  return;
}
```

and similarly in operator- add:

```
if (amount <0) {
  operator+(-amount);
  return;
}
```

Edit: by the way, be very careful about typos like:

```
if(amount = (-amount))
```

which assigns -amount to amount, then tests if amount is equal to zero!

Comment: oh yes, i forgot i left that in there that was just a note i was staring at reminding me what i wanted the if to do.  thank you.